# mysql - add header to query across join

Tags: mysql

I have the following so far:

```
   SELECT D.department AS dept, C.name AS subdept
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT department FROM classes WHERE web != 0 ORDER BY department,name LIMIT 5) D
    LEFT JOIN classes C ON (C.department = D.department)
    ORDER BY D.department,C.name
```

Which results in something like:

```
+------+-------------------------------+
| dept | subdept                       |
+------+-------------------------------+
| BOOK | CHILDRENS BOOKS               |
| BOOK | DVD'S                         |
| CLOT | ACCESSORIES                   |
| CLOT | APRONS                        |
| FEED | BIBS & BURP CLOTHS            |
| FEED | BOTTLE & FOOD WARMERS         |
+------+-------------------------------+
```

What Im trying to get is a 'header' for the each department with a null subdept value such as:

```
+------+-------------------------------+
| dept | subdept                       |
+------+-------------------------------+
| BOOK | null                          |
| BOOK | CHILDRENS BOOKS               |
| BOOK | DVD'S                         |
| CLOT | null                          |    
| CLOT | ACCESSORIES                   |
| CLOT | APRONS                        |
| FEED | null                          |    
| FEED | BIBS & BURP CLOTHS            |
| FEED | BOTTLE & FOOD WARMERS         |
+------+-------------------------------+
```

The structure of the tables: departments table has id primary key to classes department field as foreign key.

Departmens:     id     | name (of department)
Classes:    department | name (of class)

Based on what DanfromGermany has shown me I have:

```
SELECT D.department AS dept, C.name AS subdept
FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT department FROM classes WHERE web != 0 ORDER BY department,name  LIMIT 5) D
LEFT JOIN classes C ON (C.department = D.department)
GROUP BY D.department, C.name WITH ROLLUP
```

Which now gives:

```
+--------+-------------------------------+
| dept   | subdept                       |
+--------+-------------------------------+
| BOOK   | CHILDRENS BOOKS               |
| BOOK   | DVD'S                         |
| BOOK   | [NULL]                        |
| CLOT   | ACCESSORIES                   |
| CLOT   | APRONS                        |
| CLOT   | [NULL]                        |
| FEED   | BIBS & BURP CLOTHS            |
| FEED   | BOTTLE & FOOD WARMERS         |
| FEED   | [NULL]                        |
| GEAR   | BOOSTER CAR SEATS             |
| GEAR   | CAR SEAT ACCESSORIES          |
| GEAR   | [NULL]                        |
| GIFT   | BABY BASKETS & DIAPER CAKES   |
| GIFT   | BANKS                         |
| GIFT   | [NULL]                        |
| [NULL] | [NULL]                        |
+--------+-------------------------------+
```

OK last edit:

It works by subquery to use order by:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT D.department AS dept, C.name AS subdept
FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT department FROM classes WHERE web != 0 ORDER BY department,name  LIMIT 5) D
LEFT JOIN classes C ON (C.department = D.department)
GROUP BY D.department, C.name WITH ROLLUP
) T
ORDER BY dept,subdept
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to have a `GROUP BY` clause,
then use `WITH ROLLUP`.

See in the middle of that page:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Or google for "GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP mysql"

Something like this (untested):

```
SELECT D.department AS dept, C.name AS subdept
FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT department FROM classes WHERE web != 0 ORDER BY department,name  LIMIT 5) D
LEFT JOIN classes C ON (C.department = D.department)
GROUP BY dept, subdept WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY D.department,C.name
```

Comment: OH NOOO its in german! Definitely going to check this out though. thanks!

Comment: It worked with a little modification, problem now is ORDER BY is erroring out and I really need to reverse the subdept order.

Comment: I changed the link to `/en/`, sorry, stupid default language ;)
Try to change it this way: `ORDER BY dept, subdept`

Comment: Not a problem at all. I better know enough to search for the english version. I amended the question to show the utlimate result. I actually had to use the result above as a subquery to use order by. Thanks again btw, that is a good function to know.